# Get the most common appearing lines from file in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, unix, grep

I have a text file that has various words per line.
How can I find the 12 most frequent appearing lines in the file and display them?
I am not very good with scripting commands.

If I could get the command and an explanation so that I can understand how to use it and expand my knowledge on commands it would be great!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922357/find-most-frequent-line-in-file-in-bash

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can easily do this with built-in commands.

- Feed the contents of the file `sort`. We need this for the next step.
- This goes to `uniq -c`. It will count the unique occurrence of each line. If the similar lines are not adjacent, this wouldn't have worked without sorting before.
- Then, feed it to another `sort`, which now sorts in reversed order (`r`) and based on the numeric (`n`) interpretation of the `uniq` output. We need the numeric option since otherwise, the space in front of the numbers would lead to wrong results (see [GNU `sort`'s help](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) for more).
- Finally, only show the first twelve lines with `head`.

The command would then be:

```
sort test.txt | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 12
```

The output here contains the actual count of the occurrences.

To only get the raw list of lines, you can pipe the output to `sed`:

```
sort test.txt | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 12 | sed -E 's/^ *[0-9]+ //g'
```

---

#### Example:

```
I'm not there very often
I'm not there very often
Look at me!
Look at me!
Look at me!
Hello there!
Hello there!
Hello there!
Hello there!
Hello there!
Hello there!
```

Output from the first command, but only selecting 2 from `head`:

```
6 Hello there!
3 Look at me!
```

Output from the second command:

```
Hello there!
Look at me!
```

Comment: You have to sort it before using `uniq`.

Comment: @slhck:Thank you!One question:The `sort -rn` sorts in reverse order using as sorting field the number next to each line produced by `uniq -c`?I thought that something like `k1` or something like that would be used

Comment: @Jim Exactly. `r` reverses, and `n` numerically sorts on the number produced by `uniq`. What exactly do you mean with `k1`?

Comment: @slhck:I was trying to figure out these commands using `man` and I understood that a syntax using `-k` something must be used to choose the field to sort by

Comment: @cYrus:What is the edge case that a sort is needed beforehand?

Comment: @Jim You have to sort it before because `uniq` only acts on consecutive equal lines. As for the `-k`, you can use it to specify any position you want to sort by, which in this case is not needed.

Comment: @slhck:So the `rn` will sort on the available numeric and since in this case there is only 1 it will sort on the count?

Comment: @Jim So to speak. `sort` will – in this case – only consider the numeric string at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Chances are that sort has options that make uniq unnecessary.

Comment: @DanielBeck Do you have an idea how to easily remove the actual numbers output by sort, regardless of the number of digits?

Comment: Cut -f2- and specify the delimiter inserted after the number with -d? Not on a computer right now s I can't test it.

Comment: @DanielBeck The delimiter is a space, which is also used to indent `sort`'s numbers. Therefore the solution breaks with different result numbers. Might be easier though to remove this in a post-processing step.

Comment: @slhck:This works but it seems I don't need `sort -rn`.`sort -r` also works

Comment: @user65971 Indeed, but I guess it would be best to be as explicit as possible to avoid unforeseen errors in the future.

Comment: @slhck:Ok, but I don't really get how `sort` works now :(.Does this mean that if it finds a numeric field it sorts on that?

Comment: @user65971 It would sort on numbers, yes, but also ignores whitespace. Without `-n`, for example `____3` (where `_` means a space) would come before `1`. This is obviously not what we want. See more in the [GNU sort invocation help](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html).

Comment: For future reference, this works on large amounts of data (millions of lines) without consuming huge amounts of RAM.

Answer (score 3):

If your distro have [logtop](https://github.com/JulienPalard/logtop)

```
cat your_file | logtop
```

If your file is constantly growing, like a log file, try :

```
tail -f your_log | logtop
```